# Constructor or Assignment Operator

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

Can you help me is there definition in C++ standard that describes which one will be called constructor or assignment operator in this case:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CTest
{
public:

 CTest() : m_nTest(0)
 {
  cout << "Default constructor" << endl;
 }

 CTest(int a) : m_nTest(a)
 {
  cout << "Int constructor" << endl;
 }

 CTest(const CTest& obj)
 {
  m_nTest = obj.m_nTest;
  cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
 }

 CTest& operator=(int rhs)
 {
  m_nTest = rhs;
  cout << "Assignment" << endl;
  return *this;
 }

protected:
 int m_nTest;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 CTest b = 5;

 return 0;
}
```

Or is it just a matter of compiler optimization?

Comment: Can there be any difference between "CTest b(5)" and "CTest b = 5" depending on compiler?

Comment: No, the first syntax is general C++ syntax for creating an instance of a class and supplying arguments to the constructor. The second syntax is just an alternative wording that you can use if the constructor takes exactly one argument. It exists so that C code will compile without modification.

Comment: @joefis why you give you answer just as comment? Can you give some prove pls of what you said?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening here depends a bit on your compiler. It could create a temporary object using the int constructor and then copy construct b from that temporary. It will most likely elide the copy constructor call however. In neither case will the assignment operator be used.

Comment: Can there be any difference between "CTest b(5)" and "CTest b = 5" depending on compiler?

Comment: @ju Yes, that's what we are saying. The first will not use the copy constructor, the second might.

Comment: Can you tell me why in the second case, compiler can decide to create temporary CTest object and call copy constructor at all? My theory was that by standard this 2 cases are absolutely equal :(

Comment: @ju Bottom line - because the C++ Standard says it can - I'm afraid your theory is wrong. The copy constructor (which is what the Ctest b = 3 implies) requires an object of type CTest, but you are giving it an int, so the compiler can if it wishes construct a temporary using the other constructor, and some older compilers will do exactly that.

Comment: AFAIK, the answer given by Konrad is correct. A compiler that constructs a temporary and then calls the copy constructor here does not conform to the standard.

Comment: @Axel: to expand a bit, Konrad cited that the Standard encourages compiler to optimize. "encourages" is different from "mandates".

Comment: If behavior is the same in both compiler decisions then compiler can use either case, whatever it finds optimal to fulfill required optimization settings.
What does make a difference is if copy constructor and copy assignment method are different (different code). Then compiler must use explicitly what has been told to him by the code.

Answer (score 13):

It’s always the constructor taking an `int` that’s called in this case. This is called an *implicit conversion* and is semantically equivalent to the following code:

```
CTest b(5);
```

The assignment operator is *never* invoked in an initialisation. Consider the following case:

```
CTest b = CTest(5);
```

Here, we call the constructor (taking an `int`) explicitly and then use that temporary value to initialise `b`. But once again, no assignment operator is *ever* called.

Strictly speaking, pre-C++17 both cases could call the copy (or move) constructor after creating an object of type `CTest`. But in fact the C++ standard actively encouraged compilers to optimise the copy constructor call here<sup>1</sup>, and all compilers have optimised this for decades.

Since C++17, a copy constructor is *no longer* called for the code above: even though the code still looks as if a copy (or move) were performed, the value of `CTest(5)` is constructed directly into the storage of `b`, no temporary is created.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> See ISO/IEC 14882:1998 [class.copy]/15. This is known as [copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (in particular *URVO*, which confusingly stands for “unnamed return value optimisation”, even though it also applies in initialisation expressions which are not return statements).

<sup>2</sup> See ISO/IEC 14882:2017 [dcl.init]/17.6.1 ([working draft N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.1)).

Comment: +1, but I would try to avoid 'default' in the sentence 'default constructor taking an int'. I think it will be clearer to just say 'the int constructor' or 'the constructor taking an int'. Default has an specific meaning (no-argument) in the standard.

Comment: Assignment operator IS called if constructor and assignment operator methods are different code.

Comment: @BJovke No — never inside an initialisation.

Comment: this answer is inappropriate because it has no sources. citations like §12.8/15 only make sense within the context of a particular version of the c++ std which is not specified, and of which there are way too many, so no actual citation is being provided.

also, i consider this answer WRONG until the seeing proof to the contrary, because anyone can state their opinions as facts if not required to produce sources. (continues)

Comment: (continued) `CTest b = CTest(5);` literally states: call constructor () for b, call constructor (5) for a temp, call assignment for b from the temp, and destroy the temp. in general, a c++ compiler is not allowed to make "top down" optimizations by assuming properties of constructors and operators. eg: `a + b - b` might be optimized to `a` if a and b are int, but cannot do that for the general case where a and b might be a user defined type. in contrast, the compiler is expected to compile the code as written and then aggressively optimize the resulting intermediate/low level code. (continues)

Comment: (continued) optimizations like the one involving ints above are possible only because the "functions" being called to  process those ints (constructors, assignments, operators) are all intrinsics, and thus the compiler "knows" their properties, and this knowledge is expressed in optimization rules specific to those intrinsics. so optimizations run strictly bottom up once the code is translated as written. note that i don't know if there is an exception to this behavior for the specific case of `A a = A(...);`, but it sounds unlikely, and the burden of proof is on whoever says unlikely things.

Comment: @Lanchon First off, I didn’t need to cite *any* source, since the question isn’t tagged [tag:language-lawyer]. You’re right that I should have specified the standard version since the paragraph numbers unfortunately move around (but note that this answer was written pre-C++11 where we lived in an idyllic world where the standard didn’t change every two years; citing standard sections without version was *the norm* back then). Secondly, although there are *some* subtleties around copy elision, the basic concepts are fairly basic and you can easily verify yourself that this is happening here. …

Comment: @Lanchon (…) Your analysis of the code is completely wrong. Notably, nothing in this code says to perform assignment (`=` does *not* mean assignment in initialisation). These are basic C++ semantics. You’re right that the C++ compiler may *not* generally perform optimisations that change observable effects, but copy elision is explicitly excluded from that. The fact that we are passing an intrinsic type, by contrast, is irrelevant: the constructors still have side-effects, so under normal circumstances the compiler couldn’t omit the calls.

Comment: laugh all you want, this answer is invalid without sources. language lawyering does not enter into it: you are making the seemingly wild claim that the compiler makes sequence of calls different than those explicit in the source code, and not providing sources for it. for context, i seem to remember that not even `a + b - b` and `a * (1 / b)` in GGC get simplified to `a` and `a / b` for floating point numbers, due to rounding issues making those expressions not equivalent, unless a specific compiler flag for lax FP is enabled (which is similar to the `strictfp` modifier in java).

Comment: @Lanchon Again, this answer isn’t making any wild claims at all, it’s merely explaining *basic C++ concepts*. There are countless answers on this site which explain how initialisation in C++ works. I don’t have to repeat these explanations here.

Comment: no, you just have to provide a valid citation, or else refrain from answering. see how i'm lazy and didn't research the issue at all? how i didn't look for any references? this is why i didn't post an answer myself and only commented on yours. my comment is that your answer is not to be taken seriously without citations. have a good one!

Comment: @Lanchon The thing is: you’re entitled to be lazy, but you’re not entitled to my work. But as a simple service to you I’m still letting you know that your comments are still wrong on a basic factual level. If you are curious and want to learn C++ you can use this information to look for more. Or feel free to ignore it if your aim was to score cheap points instead of learning.

Answer (score 5):

`CTest b = 5;` is an exact equivalent of `CTest b(CTest(5));` Two constructors are involved: one taking an `int` (implicitly converting from integer 5), and the copy constructor. The assignment operator is in no way involved here.

The compiler may well optimize out the unnecessary copy, so the result would be as if you had typed `CTest b(5)`. Therefore at runtime, both seeing "Copy constructor" printed (GCC with the `-fno-elide-constructors` option) or not (GCC by default) would be valid output of the program.

However, conceptually the compiler is required to check if an accessible and suitable copy constructor exists. The form `CTest b = 5;` would fail to compile if a) the copy constructor is private/protected (not accessible) or b) the copy constructor takes the argument by non-const reference (can't accept a temporary from `CTest(5)` - VC++ may accept it as a non-standard compiler extension, though).

The morale is: there is no easy way to tell where and how many times the copy constructor is called in a program by looking at the code. Copying can be often omitted, and therefore you should never rely on the side-effects of the copy constructor. If it does what it is supposed to do, then it shouldn't matter to you if the compiler eliminates some unnecessary copy constructor calls.