# what 's difference between copy construct function and = operator

Tags: c++

I write a simple code,My question is:why item_base just call constrcut function?Should item_base call "copy construct  function" ?I observe that when I create item_base2,it calls "copy construct function",but item_base doesn't call "copy construct  function".what's the difference?

```
class Item_base {
    public:
        Item_base();
        Item_base(int);
        Item_base(const Item_base &base);
        void operator=(const Item_base &item);
        virtual ~Item_base();
};

Item_base::Item_base()
{
    cout << "construct function" << endl;
}

Item_base::Item_base(int a)
{
    cout << "arg construct function" << endl;
}
Item_base::Item_base(const Item_base &base)
{
    cout << "copy function" << endl;
}

void Item_base::operator=(const Item_base &item)
{
    cout << "= operator" << endl;
}

Item_base::~Item_base()
{
}


int main()
{
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    Item_base item_base = Item_base(1);//construct function
    Item_base item_base2 = item_base;//copy construct  function
    Item_base item_base3;
    item_base3 = item_base2;// =operator function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between assignment operator and copy constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706040/whats-the-difference-between-assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor)

Comment: Actually, this is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847787/constructor-or-assignment-operator

Comment: I believe in the first case the constructor of `Item_base(1)` is called and then the compiler just optimises out the copying of a temporary object here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "copy elision" or "copy constructor elision". The C++ standard permits the implementation to omit certain copies. The copy from the temporary object `Item_base(1)` to the variable `item_base` is one such copy.

The same applies to moves in C++11.

So, when you define `item_base`, in your implementation it is simply constructed using the argument `1`, instead of a temporary being constructed and then copied. All worthwhile compilers implement copy elision, although if you disable it with compiler options you would see two constructors called here.

When you define `item_base2`, `item_base` must be copied since there is no other way available to initialize `item_base2`.

When you define `item_base3` it is constructed with no arguments.

When you assign to `item_base3` it already exists, and so there is of course no construction. The assignment operator is called.

Answer (score 0):

item_base don't use the copy constructor because the object is **already** constructed.
You're just assigning `item_base3`, you don't re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

A **copy** constructor is called when you **COPY** an already constructed object to another **NEW** object being created. The call is implicit.

```
Item_base z;
Item_base x = z; //Copying `z` into `x`
```

An assignment operator is used for explicit assignment. Not necessarily while constructing;

```
Item_base y;
y = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

To be completely clear, the copy constuctor is called for both

```
Item_base a2 = a1;

Item_base a2(a1);
```

The assignment operator is not called for either.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Constructor deals with  creation a new object by using existing object, whereas Assignment operator works between two existing objects i.e just assigning values of one object to other.

Ex:(copy constructor)

```
Item_base ib1;
Item_base ib2 = ib1; or Item_base ib2(ib1);
```

Ex:(Assignment Operator)

```
Item_base ib1;
Item_base ib2
ib1=ib2;
```